# How to copy range from certain cell to last non empty cell in certain column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy an excel table form one workbook to another.
I have run-time error 1004 when trying to copy the range, using variable x to identify last non empty cell in F column.

```
Sub button_click()

Dim x As Long
x = Range("F100").End(xlUp).Row
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("ws").Range("A1:F36").Copy 'works

Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("ws").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(x, 6)).Copy 'does not work run, time error 1004

NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) 
End Sub
```

I expect the output to be equal to a copied range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your attempt but that may be more of a reflection on me, not you.

I haven't adjusted your code, I've just attempted to fix the line that is in error so check to see what I've changed.

```
Sub Button_click()
    Dim x As Long

    x = Range("F100").End(xlUp).Row

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("ws").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & Cells(x, 6).Address).Copy

    NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

... mind you, the 2 copy lines together are a little dubious.  The first copy will be overwritten by the second, but having said that, one looks to be a hardcoded attempt, the other is the line you are trying to make dynamic and for that reason, I removed it from my answer.

See if that helps you anyway,

Answer (score 0):

My *GUESS* is that it has to do with the fact that the `Cells` reference in this bit of code `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(x, 6))` isn't qualified with the workbook.

Try this, maybe:

```
Sub button_click()

Dim x As Long
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

With Workbooks("wb").Worksheets("ws")
    x = .Range("F100").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(x, 6)).Copy
End With

NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) 
End Sub
```

notice that by adding the `With...` statement and then including `Range(.Cells(` rather than `Range(Cells(` we are now explicitly stating that the cells we are referring to are within this worksheet.

Hopefully this does the trick!